# How to modify the value of an attribute of an object after a value has already been assigned?

Tags: java

Developing this simple code:

```
    public class Car {
    String owner;
    int year;

    public Car (String owner, int year) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.year = year;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
```

On the other class, you want to create an object, assigning one value to the owner of the car, and a year to the car, and after this you want to modify the value of the owner of the car and modify the year of the car:

```
public OtherClass {
Car car = new Car("John", 2010);

car.setOwner("Mark"); // It causes error
car.setYear(2014); // It causes error
}
```

However, after you create an object and you put values on this object, how can you change the values of this object?
If you write: car.owner = "Mark" and car.year = 2014, the IDE doesn´t recognize it.

Comment: Ok, I tried it. But it does not work, because it appears the following error:

"Multiple markers at this line
- Sintax error on token ".", @expected after this token
- Sintax error on token ";", @expected"

Comment: John, look at the answers below. Getters and Setters have to be implement by you. They're no automatic properties.

Comment: The problem in your code is that you didn't close the bracket of the constructor

Comment: While you are setting the values, that code should be inside the method, you are directly written inside the class .

Comment: zazz, it was fixed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hard to explain in comments. so I am posting solution here.
It was compilation error. You can create OtherClass.java and paste this code run main method it will work.

```
class Car {
    private String owner;
    private int year;

    public Car(String owner, int year) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void setOwner(String value) {
        this.owner = value;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public void setYear(int value) {
        this.year = value;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }
}


public class OtherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car("John", 2010);

        car.setOwner("Mark");
        car.setYear(2014);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You answered my question :)